# Hi, I am having trouble with setting up drupal with a symbolic link. I keep getting this error

Tags: drupal

[image]

[image]

It is the first time I set up drupal, and I have following the steps from this webpage and im stuck on the final part of step 6. Which is

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/drupal /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

it states it can not create a symbolic link

https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-drupal-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04-with-nginx-and-lets-encrypt/

thank you for your help!

Comment: it LOOKS like yuo already have a symlink there.  `sudo ls -alhF` will give us more information on the symlink - chances are it already goes to where you think it does and as such is already in place and **does not need to be created again**

Comment: sure just give me a min to vpn into my pc thank you so much

Comment: just added the photo.

Comment: ... you did an `ls` on the wrong directory... I wanted an `ls` from the same directory your first one was.  `ls -alhF /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and then post THAT output.  Also, I suggest you copy/paste the content in instead of screenshots - it's usually considered Bad Form to screenshot terminal output.

Comment: hi here it is, it i just shows my drupal file a and the default, thank you for helping me                    
root@admin956-VirtualBox:~# ls -alhf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
.. . drupal default

Comment: add the content with a paste into your question as an edit.  what i'm looking for is the destination of the symlink and it loks like it doesn't exist.  Try removing `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/drupal` then recreating the symlink like you tried.)